# SWF File loading in Firefox but Not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, flash

hey well I have the following code loading an swf

```
<object style="visibility: visible;" id="myContent" data="http://www.norble.com/demo/mp3/playlist/preview.swf?t=1286488645000?stageW=525&amp;stageH=300&amp;pathToFiles=&amp;settingsPath=http://www.norble.com/demo/mp3/playlist/xml/player_settings.xml&amp;xmlPath=http://www.norble.com/demo/mp3/playlist/xspf.php?id=4&amp;imageWidth=140&amp;imageHeight=200" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="300">
    </object>
```

but for some reason it's not displaying the playlist in internet explorer, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statically embedding flash into IE is a little different than firefox. If you look at the documentation [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html) there is an extra object tag that's needed for IE. Their example is pasted below for reference.

Though really you should be using SWFObject2 http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ to embed your content. But the static is good as a fall back if javascript isn't enabled.

```
<object id="myFlashContent" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="120">
    <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="300" height="120">
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="/go/getflashplayer">
           <img src="/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to write cross-browser SWF embeds is using SWFObject.

Check it out here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/